# Vue bypass html into sub-sub component

Tags: vuejs2

Lets say, I have the following vuejs structure:

```
<!-- MainComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <childcomponent></childcomponent>
</template>

<!-- ChildComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <grandchild></grandchild>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- GrandchildComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        FooBar
        <slot name="actions"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

If I want to set a value for the grandchild-slot "actions" in the child-component, I have to do this:

```
<!-- ChildComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <grandchild>
            <template slot="actions">Actions from ChildComponent</template>
        </grandchild>
    </div>
</template>
```

But how to bypass "actions" from the MainComponent? I tried this, but thats not working:

```
<!-- MainComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <childcomponent>
        <template slot="actions" slot-scope="props">
            Actions from MainComponent
        </template>
    </childcomponent>
</template>

<!-- ChildComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <grandchild>
            <slot name="actions">
                <template slot="actions" slot-scope="props">
                    Actions from ChildComponent
                </template>
            </slot>
        </grandchild>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I think the only possible way of doing it, is only over the render function (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

The main idea behind it is to write instead of html templates for ChildComponent.vue and GrandchildComponent.vue custom render functions.

A complete tutorial for a similar usecase can be found here:
https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-tutorial/wiki